# How can I prevent Perl from interpreting double-backslash as single-backslash character?

Tags: perl

How can I print a string (single-quoted) containing double-backslash `\\` characters as is without making Perl somehow interpolating it to single-slash `\`? I don't want to alter the string by adding more escape characters also.

```
my $string1 = 'a\\\b';
print $string1; #prints 'a\b'

my $string1 = 'a\\\\b';
    #I know I can alter the string to escape each backslash
    #but I want to keep string as is.
print $string1; #prints 'a\\b'

#I can also use single-quoted here document
#but unfortunately this would make my code syntactically look horrible.
my $string1 = <<'EOF';
a\\b
EOF
print $string1; #prints a\\b, with newline that could be removed with chomp
```

Comment: Let me guess... dealing with Windows file paths?

Comment: No I'm passing single-quoted-strings to subroutines and those strings are containing double-backslashes.

Comment: Oh. Could you give an example? You shouldn't have to escape double quotes inside single quotes. `'She said, "you don't have to escape double quotes in single quotes."'` is fine. So is using `qq[]` if you want interpolation but don't want to escape double quotes.

Comment: Sorry: edited the comment. I meant double-backslashes instead of double-quotes

Comment: The only places that a double backslash is interpreted as a single backslash is within string literals in your program. If they are read from a file or contained in a variable then they are left as they are. Do you really need your string literals to be in a specific form? Could you explain why?

Answer (score 10):

The only quoting construct in Perl that doesn't interpret backslashes at all is the single-quoted here document:

```
my $string1 = <<'EOF';
a\\\b
EOF
print $string1; # Prints a\\\b, with newline
```

Because here-docs are line-based, it's unavoidable that you will get a newline at the end of your string, but you can remove it with `chomp`.

Other techniques are simply to live with it and backslash your strings correctly (for small amounts of data), or to put them in a `__DATA__` section or an external file (for large amounts of data).

Comment: I did not know that!

Comment: Single-quoted here document solution on each string I have would make my code syntactically look horrible.

Comment: @Omar well, I'm just laying out the facts. You can backslash your backslashes, you can use heredocs, or you can keep these paths somewhere other than in a Perl source file. To the best of my knowledge there aren't any other reasonable options, so pick the one you dislike least :)

Comment: @hobbs Option 4: Write XS module, hook into parser, write own quoting operator.

Comment: @melpomene hmm, not too crazy. Maybe tonight I will try to write a raw-quote module.

Comment: @melpomene https://github.com/arodland/Syntax-Feature-RawQuote — `perl -Msyntax=raw_quote -le 'print r\`a\\b\\c\`' `

Answer (score 7):

If you are mildly crazy, and like the idea of using experimental software that mucks about with perl's internals to improve the aesthetics of your code, you can use the [Syntax::Keyword::RawQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::RawQuote) module, on CPAN since this morning.

```
use syntax 'raw_quote';
my $string1 = r'a\\\b';
print $string1; # prints 'a\\\b'
```

Thanks to @melpomene for the inspiration.

Comment: This is inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Since the backslash interpolation happens in string literals, perhaps you could declare your literals using some other arbitrary symbol, then substitute them for something else later.

```
my $string = 'a!!!b';
$string =~ s{!}{\\}g;
print $string; #prints 'a\\\b'
```

Of course it doesn't have to be `!`, any symbol that does not conflict with a normal character in the string will do. You said you need to make a number of strings, so you could put the substitution in a function

```
sub bs {
    $_[0] =~ s{!}{\\}gr
}

my $string = 'a!!!b';
print bs($string); #prints 'a\\\b'
```

**P.S.**
That function uses the non-destructive substitution modifier `/r` introduced in `v5.14`. If you are using an older version, then the function would need to be written like this

```
sub bs {
    $_[0] =~ s{!}{\\}g;
    return $_[0];
}
```

Or if you like something more readable

```
sub bs {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s{!}{\\}g;
    return $str;
}
```